# Why is this error occurring when I use writerow?

Tags: csv, export

Why am I getting this error when I try to use writerow

db.writerow(loanList[i])
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

'''

```
import csv

header = ['Name','Results']
file = open("loanResults.csv", "w", newline = "")

a = 10000
b = [0.032,0.043,0.037,0.043,0.044,0.029,0.028,0.030]
c = [6,7,4,3,4,6,7,9,]

loanList = []

def monthlyRepayment(principalAmount,interest,year):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        finalAmount = principalAmount * ((1 + interest[i]) **year[i])
        monthlyAmount = (finalAmount / (year[i]*12))
        loanList.append(round(monthlyAmount))
        print(round(monthlyAmount))
        
testCase1 = monthlyRepayment(a,b,c)

db = csv.writer(file)
db.writerow(header)

for i in range(len(loanList)):
    db.writerows(loanList[i])

file.close()
```

'''

Comment: Because per [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#): *writerows ...Write all elements in rows (an iterable of row objects as described above) to the writer’s file object ...*. By doing `loanList[i]` you are slicing the list to a single element and it not an iterable. Skip the `for i in ... ` and just do `db.writerows(loanList)`. If you want to use the `for` loop the do `db.writerow(loanList[i])`

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your help. Yes, not using a for loop, I can get it to print out as a row. But I want the output over many rows (a column) and when I use db.writerow(loanList[i]) with a for loop, I still get the error:     db.writerow(loanList[i])
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Comment: To your question add the output of `print(loanList[i])`. One thing I noticed is `header = ['Name','Results']` which is two columns and `loanList.append(round(monthlyAmount))` looks to be adding only one column.